# How to break statement in a if statement in Blogger where both IF and ELSE are true?

Tags: javascript, xml, if-statement, conditional-statements, blogger

I am changing some labels (tags) in my blog so that each post may have, at least, 2 labels.

The idea is that if the post have the LABEL 1, it loads a script; else, loads another one. So far, so good, but in the posts labeled with LABEL 1, both conditions are satisfied and the two scripts are loaded and I'll explain why.

An important point (that I know it would fix my problem, but I can't change) is that posts labeled with LABEL 1 must have another label (in addition to LABEL 1), that's why both conditions are satisfied (the `if` and the `else`).

In this case, is there any way to break the execution if the first condition is satisfied? *i.e. (the post has LABEL 1 = true)*

I tried the `break`, but it looks like that it doesn't work because I don't have a loop, but a conditional statement.

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='(data:post.labels where (label => label.name in [LABEL 1"])).length gt 0'>
// WHAT TO DO IF THE POST HAS "LABEL 1"
// I WISH THE CODE BREAK HERE EVEN IF A POST WITH "LABEL 1" HAVE ANOTHER LABEL.

<b:else/>
// WHAT TO DO IF THE POST DOES NOT HAVE "LABEL 1"

</b:if>
</b:loop>
```

Comment: This can't be possible if and else true at the same time.

Comment: There's only **one** conditional expression in the code you posted.

Comment: @Pointy I think there are two, don't you?!

Comment: @pc_coder Really, man? Isn't there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: There's one conditional expression in the `<b:if>`.  By definition, the `<b:else>` will only be evaluated if that expression is `false`.

Comment: Got it, @Pointy I'll verify my code with more patience. Thank you!

Comment: @Pointy I'd guess the problem is that it's an `if` inside a `loop`. In one iteration, the condition matches, in the other iteration it doesn't.

Comment: @Bergi well ... yes? I guess so, but that's not the topic as posted.

Comment: @Bergi It was exacly this! I was running some tests here and I realized that the script was loaded six times (because there was six labels). When I deleted the first and the last line of the code, it worked! Thank you everyone!

Comment: @Pointy I apologize you because when I verified my tests, I realized that the script from `if condition` was executed repeatedly, while I thought that what was being executed it was the script from `else condition`. It was a misapprehension from me.

Comment: @vitoralves no worries! I'm glad you're making progress

Comment: I apprecite your kindness, @Pointy! God bless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code without using `b:loop`

```xml
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "label 1")'>
 <!-- do something -->
<b:else/>
 <!-- the post does not have "label 1" -->
</b:if>
```